# Как работает ++ в JAVA?

Tags: java, переменные, операторы

учу я.п. JAVA, в одном видео курсе человек привёл такой пример:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
int c = a + b++;

System.out.println(b);
```

при выводе на экран переменная `b` выдаёт значение 4, НО 4 это значение переменной `с`, а в `sout` выводится переменная `b`, изначально ведь значение переменной `b=3;`.
Почему он мне выдаёт `b++`, а не `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b++` - это увеличение значения b на 1 и возврат значения b до этого увеличения
`++b` - это увеличение значения b на 1 и возврат нового значения

Соответственно

```
b = 999;
System.out.println(b++);
System.out.println(b);
```

даст вывод

> 999
> 1000

а

```
b = 999;
System.out.println(++b);
System.out.println(b);
```

даст вывод

> 1000
> 1000

Это все, что вам нужно знать об инкременте (с декрементом то же самое, только значение b уменьшается на 1, а не увеличивается).

Соответственно, когда вы в ЛЮБОМ контексте пишете `b++`, значение `b` увеличивается на 1 и возвращается ее значение до увеличения на 1.

---

Например, что выведет следующее?

```
int b = 1;
int a = b++ + b++ + ++b;
System.out.println(a + " " + b);
```

Для того, чтобы это узнать, поработаем компьютером.
Натыкаемся на первое `b++`. `b` теперь равен (то есть в ячейку памяти с переменной `b` записывается такое значение) 2. Возвращаем же 1 (то есть значение, которое `b` имело до увеличения на 1):

```
int a = 1 + b++ + ++b;
```

Натыкаемся на второе `b++`. `b` теперь равен 3. Возвращаем же 2:

```
int a = 1 + 2 + ++b;
```

Натыкаемся на `++b`. `b` теперь равен 4. Возвращаем же 4 (то есть значение после увеличения на 1):

```
int a = 1 + 2 + 4;
```

Вывод тогда будет следующим:

> 7 4

Comment: спасибо но это я понял, префикс и постфикс, Меня интересует почему компилятор выводит не то что я хочу, я прошу вывести b=3; покажи мне 3, а он мне выводит b++ значение из переменной с.

Comment: @Miron Мне кажется, он троллит. Уже в трех ответах написали, почему 4, а он делает все делает вид, что не понимает.

Comment: и скажите ещё, какой смысл писать постфикс? если значение остаётся прежним.

Comment: @ВарЯапя лучше ты скажи, какой смысл тебе отвечать, если ты даже не пытаешь понять, что тебе пишут

Comment: @ВарЯапя посмотрите пример - только сейчас дописал

Comment: Эникейщик вот бы вам так ответили в начале вашего обучения, два препода стоят в универе и один говорит другому , мне кажется студент нас тролит.

Comment: @ВарЯапя, компилятор как раз выводит то, что вы попросили. Вы сперва просили увеличить `b` на 1 вот так `b++`, он увеличил. А потом вы попросили вывести это значение и он вам вывел 4

Comment: @ВарЯапя поправил основную часть - так будет куда понятнее

Answer (score 2):

выражение `b++;` это инкремент. Означает, что мы используем текущее значение и после увеличиваем его на единицу.

```
int c = a + b++; // с = 5 + 3;
```

в следующей строке значение `b=4`

`System.out.println(b); // b=4`

Comment: в какой следующей строке?  b=3; я вывожу b, почему 4?

Comment: @ВарЯапя, там где у вас `System.out.println(b);`

Comment: что System.out.println(b); =4 что System.out.println(b++); =4

Comment: я же не значение с вывожу, а переменную b.

Comment: @ВарЯапя, нет. Объясните, пожалуйста, откуда в `c` значение 4?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `b++` увеличивает значение `b` на единицу.

P.S. И значение `с` совсем не 4.

Comment: Если увидишь мои вопросы, просто игнорируй, даже не заходи на страницу вопроса.

Comment: @ВарЯапя Я без тебя разберусь, куда мне заходить, а куда нет. Если увидишь моё сообщение, игнорируй его, даже не читая.

Comment: я твои хамские комментарии читать не собираюсь.

Answer (score -1):

Да что же вы так путано объясняете то?

```
b++;
```

эквивалентно

```
b=b+1;
```

Comment: но в данном случае совсем не эквивалентно. Нельзя в этом коде заменить одно другим.

Comment: `++b` эквивалентно `b = b + 1`

Comment: `++b` и `b++`  в стандалон выражении идентичны, разница возникает при присвоении :)

Comment: @Эникейщик я не говорил про замену, я говорил про идентичность для понимания того что происходит

Comment: @Barmaley ну так в каждом ответе написано, что b++ увеличивает значение на единицу. Куда ещё понятнее-то?

Comment: b++ - это увеличение значения b на 1 и возврат значения b до этого увеличения
++b - это увеличение значения b на 1 и возврат нового значения (какой смысл тогда постфикса) если он возвращает прежнее значение?

Comment: @ВарЯапя, постфикс применяют часто в циклах. Когда на текущей итерации ты работаешь с текущим значением `b`, а на следующей тебе необходимо увеличенное значение на 1. Вот здесь ты и напишешь `b++`

Comment: Вот это я хотел понять, спасибо.